# reactjs value of input changed but onchange not working

Tags: reactjs

I have an input like this:

```
<input type='text' value={this.props.rate} onChange={(e)=>{this.setstate({rate: e.target.value})}} />
```

when I see the log, after the `props.rate` change by dispatch action then the value change but onChange event not working.

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: That is invalid code

Comment: You're not using `setState` properly, and it should be throwing an error tbh

Comment: But it doesn't notify an error because it didn't reach onChange event

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by simply using `componentWillReceiveProps` to `setSate` when the props change.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)
{
    if(nextProps.rate !== this.state.rate){
        this.setState({
            rate: nextProps.rate
        });
    }
}
```